# After upgrade to magento 2.3.2 images slow loading

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

After an ugrade from 2.2.8 to 2.3.2 images are loading very slow, especialy the first load. Also CPU is much higher then with 2.2.8.

I have an Nginx apache redis config.

How to speed up (fist time) image loading

Comment: Product images or everything?

Comment: Only product page images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove pub/media/catalog/product/cache . (Removing this folder frees up space.)

Run bin/magento catalog:image:resize to generate a new image cache. (This step is necessary because we’ve changed the path to cached images and must remove the previously cached images.)

Answer (score 0):

i tested this issue in all versions including magento 2.4.6
As a result configurable product has this problem in all versions of magento.
Solution @Mehdi it works. Thanks @Mehdi